# JavaScript function not working for divid.blur

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I have a situation here, I need to calculate tax on the basis of an input using JavaScript. Here is the code:

PHP CODE:

```
<tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$0.00</div></td>
          </tr>
                     <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Tax(%)</td>

              <td class="total-value"><textarea id="txp">0.00</textarea></td>
          </tr>
                    <tr>

              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Taxes</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="tax">$0.00</div></td>
          </tr>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function update_tax() {
    var txc = $("txp").val() * $("#subtotal").val() / 100;
    $("#tax").html(txc);
}

$("#txp").blur(update_tax);
```

But the function is not working. Can anyone please help me with why this is not working?

Comment: Need more information. Where/When is the event bound? Any error messages in the console?

Comment: I guess you're getting a `NaN` in your tax box?

Comment: Please elaborate on *the function is not working*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$0.00</div></td>
```

to :

```
<td class="total-value">$<span id="subtotal">0.00</span></td>
```

and your code to:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   function update_tax() {
       var txc = parseFloat($("#txp").val()) * parseFloat($("#subtotal").text()) / 100;
       $("#tax").html("$"+txc);
    }
    $("#txp").blur(update_tax);
  });
```

Now the code starts executing when the page has fully loaded. I moved the `$`-sign from the `div` and changed the `div` to a `span` (inline). So `$` and value appear on the same line.

In the multiplying function I used parseFloat to convert any string to a `float`. The content from the `textarea` can be retrieved using jQuery `val()` the content of the span using `text()`. Also in the function you used `txp` as a selector, which will refer to a node with the name `txp`. Updated it to `#txp` to select the element with `id`: `txp`.